# Embedded orbeon - how to define language

Tags: orbeon

I have an (I think via the standard way) embedded Orbeon instance:

```
<%
API.embedFormJava(
    request,            // HttpServletRequest: incoming HttpServletRequest
    out,                // Writer: where the embedded form is written
    (String) request.getAttribute("application"), // String: Form Runner app name
    (String) request.getAttribute("form"), // String: Form Runner form name
    (String) request.getAttribute("action"), // String: Form Runner action name
    (String) request.getAttribute("version"), // String: Form Runner document id (optional)
    null, // String: query string (optional)
    (Map) request.getAttribute("customHeaders") // Map<String, String>: custom HTTP headers (optional));
 %>
```

The problem is that the form-builder sometimes displayed in english instead of the locale defined in the browser and I can't get it why.
Unfortunately the documentation does not contain anything in this topic at first sight.

What is the mechanism that the embedded Orbeon use to detect the (client/browser) locale?
Can I force the (embedded) Orbeon to use a fix (available) locale instead of let it try to detect it?

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm used by Orbeon Forms is described in the section [Determination of the form's language](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/features/localization#determination-of-the-forms-language). In your case, I would:

- If you have a set language you want to be picked as a default for all users, set the `oxf.fr.default-language.*.*` property in Orbeon Forms' `properties-local.xml`.
- If the default language to be used for a given user depends on some information you have about that user, you can programmatically pass the language to use to Orbeon forms with the `fr-language` request parameter, which with `API.embedFormJava()` you provide with the penultimate parameter.

Comment: Thank you again :) I will check it tomorrow.